# What are some good ways to prevent people from copying my source code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a lot of customized javascript and layout design, and I want to prevent people from using those. Is there any practical way to do this, or do I basically just have to be happy my php code does not show? I want to at least make it difficult to copy my site.

Comment: You could try to make it as open and readable as possible and merely request that people give you credit should they decide to reuse your code.  Some people won't adhere to that request but the benefit (maintanable code, public recognition) outweighs the risk IMO.

Comment: @Mayo, while I agree that people should contribute to open solutions which will reduce the duplication of effort rampant within our industry, I think a mature deployment process for any website would be to minimize file sizes by running utilities which would strip unnecessary characters and replace long identifier names with short ones... e.g. "minify", and the process of doing so would cause obfuscation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If people really want to get access to your source code they can do that fairly easily.

It is possible to slow people down to a limited degree by obfuscating code.

See:

- http://code.google.com/p/minify/
- http://refresh-sf.com/yui/
- http://ajaxian.com/archives/utility-javascript-obfuscator

Maintaining obfuscated code is difficult. What you want to do is obfuscate it before deployment so that you can test and debug with the normal version. Debugging problems on a live site can be made a lot more difficult by the obfuscation.

Comment: hey sweet, I was looking for a way to minify forever. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Took a look at the minify one, and it looks like something worth using, even if just to reduce bandwidth. +1

Comment: I just installed the minify, boy is that key. Thanks a lot for suggesting that, it minifies reducing bandwidth, and makes the code a pain to read. Thanks again.

Comment: Google's mod_pagespeed will minify automatically, won't it? Haven't looked into it much, but it sounds like a nice "install and forget" solution.

Answer (score 12):

All client-side code can be copied. If you're a web designer, your best bet is to just brand yourself well and keep innovating so that clients are more interested in the originator than the imitator.

Answer (score 8):

There's no way to prevent people from seeing your source code. There are ways to [obfuscate](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/) it and make it difficult to reuse, but there's no way to hide it. Also note that obfuscation makes it hard to maintain as well.

Comment: some sites do, of course. i don't believe it's that widely practiced, however, because it's impossible to completely protect. anyone who really really wants your client side code is going to get it, obfuscated or not.

Comment: Yes a lot of them do, but it is done to save bandwidth and not to protect their intellectual property.

Comment: BrianLy: I'm sure it's for both reasons.

Comment: well, they minify, which isn't always the same as obfuscating. i guess PACKing is kind of both, but less obfuscating and more reducing byte transfer.

Comment: @Scarface, some kinds of obfuscation have the side benefit of making the code shorter (by changing identifiers for variables and functions, etc.), so you do see it occasionally on high traffic sites where every byte counts.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I am definitely going to use minify, I think that would be the best thing to do to make code hard to take, and really improve performance as well. Brian suggested a minifier, and it looks good. I used to think I had to delete whitespace and such manually, but this way I can still keep my code intact.

Comment: Obfuscation doesnt make anything harder to maintain becuase you have access to the original source

Comment: true, but after you fix it, you have to re-obfuscate before pushing. not "harder" per se, but more of a PITA.

Answer (score 6):

By far the most widespread method is to write so bad code that no one in their right mind would want to copy it, it's employed by approx 99% of web sites.

Is it actually a problem to you if someone snatch a piece of your code?

Sure it is a problem if someone the steal the whole site/application, but the only way you can really deal with that anyway is through standard legal means.

Comment: that is a good point, I am already seeing to have my work copyrighted when I am finished. Is your copyright still valid if you update your work? Do you have any useful advice as far as legal protection?

Comment: Under the Berne Convention, copyright applies the moment any creative work (i.e. your software) is created. There are no steps to be taken to make unauthorized copying or derivation an infringing act. To actually pursue an infringer, you may have to go through a registration on the particular version infringed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, so you are saying to pursue someone, who have to copyright a copy of your site with your government to have a reference version?

Answer (score 5):

I use the [Google Closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) for javascript. This is to reduce download size and remove redundant code but it has the added benefit of making the code much harder to read.

Answer (score 5):

I have always envied people who sell JavaScript products *because their work is always out in the open*. I think this is a terrific deterrent for anybody who has something to lose—i.e., businesses, commercial web sites, and such. The day Google (or another big search engine) offers the possibility to search in pages' source code, you can start detecting copyright infringements within minutes.

And even if that search engine option never comes up, it's still possible to find out, very quickly and effortlessly, whether a site uses stolen Javascript.

On the other hand, a minifier used by the person *stealing the code* would make this much, much harder. So some minification/obfuscation, as suggested in the other answers, is probably a good idea nevertheless.

Comment: I am going to use the google project minifier, due to its ease of use, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an obfuscator for your code which will make site loadable but not readable to the other developers - they will not have an easy way to modify and adapt it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an obfuscator, if you like. It makes the source human-unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Scare them by using copyright marks in your code and a good lawyer. If they believe that you will sue them maybe the will steal form someone else.