# Compile HTML code heavily?

Tags: javascript, html, css, compilation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to encrypt HTML, CSS and JavaScript to prevent theft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247270/how-to-encrypt-html-css-and-javascript-to-prevent-theft)
>   [What are some good ways to prevent people from copying my source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562775/what-are-some-good-ways-to-prevent-people-from-copying-my-source-code)

Is there any good way to compile HTML? I'm working on a page that contains HTML code and some CSS and JavaScript. Is there anyway that I can compile it so that other people cant easily grab it through source?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you worried about people grabbing your HTML?  Fact of life is most people over value things they wrote.

Comment: The answer is no.  Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247270/how-to-encrypt-html-css-and-javascript-to-prevent-theft/3247301#3247301
Why is this such an oft-repeated question?

Comment: The word you are looking for is 'obfuscate.' 'compile' makes no sense in this context.

Comment: I know for certain that what I have coded will be emulated by other users, what Im hoping for is to reduce that factor as much as possible.

Answer (score 13):

No. There is no way to stop someone from reading the source as the content needs to be served in a format that the browser understands and can parse a DOM tree from.

You can perform minification on the JavaScript that can provide very shallow obsfucation, but that's about it.

Answer (score 3):

HTML is not code, it is markup.

The html needs to be delivered to the browser and if the browser has a view source function it will always show the html.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to use Zend Optimizer, Zend Encoder and Zend SafeGuard
http://www.zend.com/products/guard/
http://www.webhostgear.com/184.html