# HTML source code encryption technique

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt HTML, CSS and JavaScript to prevent theft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247270/how-to-encrypt-html-css-and-javascript-to-prevent-theft)

Is there any technique in PHP language, or some software available to encrypt the html code that is seen while clicking on view source and view generated source on browsers.Can the code be encrypted to binary strings ie( 0 and 1) format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People will always be able to get to your html - even if you did find some way to obfuscate / hide it, maybe using javascript, anyone can always use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or similar to view it.

Answer (score 3):

No. The browser needs valid HTML to display the document. There is no way to encrypt HTML.

The whole world is serving pages that are not encrypted, so it stands to reason it's not necessary, either.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can obscure it a bit, but in the end your browser needs to read it, and it reads HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: no. You can make the HTML ugly by removing whitespace, but the browser needs to be able to read it! You can obfuscate your Javascript pretty darn well by removing whitespace and newlines and using short or crazy variable names: for example see [here.](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx)