# how to encrypt html page source code using javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, browser, obfuscation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt HTML, CSS and JavaScript to prevent theft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247270/how-to-encrypt-html-css-and-javascript-to-prevent-theft)

Please tell how to encrypt html page surce code for any webpage using javascript function if not possible then please tell alternative ways..

Comment: There are a MILLION questions on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247270/how-to-encrypt-html-css-and-javascript-to-prevent-theft

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: We need more info. What part of the HTML do you want to encrypt? Just the text? Or also the html tags? Why do you want to encrypt it? Is it to avoid data being stolen in the way (evesdropping)? Or do you want the end user to be unable to see how you made the page?

Comment: These question i have already answered take a look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42952848/7751463

Answer (score 0):

In order for the source to be rendered, it has to be decrypted in the browser and a DOM constructed, which which point the user can use a DOM inspector to access the DOM and serialize it back to HTML (thus creating a reasonable facsimile of the original HTML).

Thus there is no way, alternative or otherwise.