# Encrypt html code in source view

Tags: php, javascript, html, encryption

I am using an video embed code (Similar to youtube's embed code) and I would like to Encrypt or hash a part of the code (The Video id or filename of the video). 
It is important to me that a user that views the source code of the page wont be able to view those items.
Is there a way I can do so? Any recommendation?

I'd add that my site is using php.

For example, here is an youtube embed code:

```
<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/fRgWBN8yt_E?hl=en_US&amp;version=3"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/fRgWBN8yt_E?hl=en_US&amp;version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Lets say I would want to change the part:

```
value="http://www.youtube.com/v/fRgWBN8yt_E?hl=en_US&amp;version=3">
```

Into:

```
value="sdfj8435437fjdfs8458543(Some Kind of hashing or encryption)">
```

Thanks,

Nimi

Comment: [See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16660190/1729885). To paraphrase: *"Always remember: if the browser can show it, anyone can copy it, you can only make it (a tiny bit) harder."*

Comment: http://www.iwebtool.com/html_encrypter is this what you're searching for?

Comment: Your only option may be to dynamically generate a key in the HTML response that gets passed to the video resource.  Then in the server's handler for the video, validate the key.  Keys can expire after a certain amount of time, certain number of uses, etc.  In the end, users can still use it at least at first.  You'll end up looking for a balance between development effort, user aggravation, and security.

Comment: you can't have things looking like one thing in source code inspection and other when being executed by the browser. That's how html rolls

Comment: @jakee well actually that *IS* possible. You can write one thing in the HTML, and then decrypt/decode it using JS at runtime. 'View Source' will show the encrypted code, but the element inspector will always show the decrypted one. What OP wants is possible, just terribly pointless.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes:No; what the OP _actually_ wants (but doesn't realize it) is to hide it from the inspector too.  That is impossible.

Comment: @Slaks I know, I as responding to Jakee. What he described in his comment is possible (hide in source), just pointless (cannot hide from runtime inspection).

Answer (score 9):

That is completely, fundamentally impossible.

No matter what you do, the user can see the final result in the inspector or network tab.

Instead, you can place a single-use token in the URL so that it will only work once.

Comment: That answer was blessed by SLaks's powers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want the user to find the video in YouTube or some other video sharing platform.

Well, that is indeed impossible if the video is open to the public. Instead, consider using Vimeo Plus, where you can hide the uploaded videos from the public and only allow embedding in a white list of predefined URLs

Answer (score 0):

Step -1 ) Convert ASCII VALUE To Hexadecimal

ASCII VALUE - http://www.youtube.com/v/fRgWBN8yt_Ehl=en_US&version=3

HexaDecimal VALUE - 
         68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 79 6f 75 74 75 62 65 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 76 2f 66 52 67 57 42 4e 38 79 74 5f 45 3f 68 6c 3d 65 6e 5f 55 53 26 61 6d 70 3b 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 33

Step - 2) Replace Spaces with %
   ie -
     68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%77%77%77%2e%79%6f%75%74%75%62%65%2e%63%6f%6d%2f%76%2f%66%52%67%57%42%4e%38%79%74%5f%45%3f%68%6c%3d%65%6e%5f%55%53%26%61%6d%7%3b%76%65%72%73%69%6f%6e%3d%33

step - 3) use javascript function unescape('68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%77%77%77%2e%79%6f%75%74%75%62%65%2e%63%6f%6d%2f%76%2f%66%52%67%57%42%4e%38%79%74%5f%45%3f%68%6c%3d%65%6e%5f%55%53%26%61%6d%7%3b%76%65%72%73%69%6f%6e%3d%33');

step -4 )
example -
unescape('%67%6f%6f%67%6c%65%2e%63%6f%6d')">Test
i.e these is for opening google.com

in your case use

```html
<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie" value="<script>unescape('68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%77%77%77%2e%79%6f%75%74%75%62%65%2e%63%6f%6d%2f%76%2f%66%52%67%57%42%4e%38%79%74%5f%45%3f%68%6c%3d%65%6e%5f%55%53%26%61%6d%7%3b%76%65%72%73%69%6f%6e%3d%33</script>"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/fRgWBN8yt_E?hl=en_US&amp;version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```