# Best way to prevent someone reading the source code

Tags: php, mysql, security, encoder

there are some form which I want to hide it from being read by someone else.. what do you think is the best way to doing that?

1. hiding the source code in mysql and use query select to view the form.
2. encrypt the page with encoder.
3. is there any other way?

Comment: From whom do you what hide your source?

Comment: What sort of code do you want to protect? HTML/JS?

Comment: If you re talking about PHP source code, then you don't have to worry about people reading your code. It does not get transmitted over the browser. You only have to prevent people from being able to access your server ftp wise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hiding PHP Code**

If you're worried about PHP source code, providing you're keeping it on your server and not distributing it, it's all down to keeping your server secure. Nobody can read it without server access (or the mis-configuration of your server). You've included the `mysql` tag, you can apply the same logic as PHP for that.

**Obfuscating HTML**

There is little to no point, if someone wants your markup, a few entities here and there aren't going to stop them. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671819/1400370)

Comment: Write it after an "end-of-file" mark.  It's fairly easy to do on z/OS.  To anyone who doesn't know it's there, it looks like there's nothing after end-of file. I can post some "how to" code if you'd like to see it.