# Conceal URL in javascript code ( URL generated by PHP )

Tags: javascript, php, url

I am looking for a solution to the following:

I have a piece of JS code, that performs a redirection to a URL that is constructed with PHP, and that redirection is only done when the user presses a button on a confirmation dialog.

The code is, as follows:

```
function one() {
    window.location.replace("<?php 

if($new_redir == "1")  {

echo "$new_second_redirect_URL/?token=$hash";

}

else  {

echo "$second_redirect_URL/?token=$hash";

}

?>");
}
```

It works perfectly fine. What I wanna do is conceal the URL that is displayed in the source code when a user opens the page.

What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: If you hid the url how would the browser know where to go?  There is no effective way to do what you want, another approach is required.

Comment: check this question's ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712426/hide-url-from-atag-on-view-page-source

Comment: What I mostly wanna do, is make sure automated bots cannot get that URL directly by scanning the source code of the page. Legitimate human visitors are not my problem. As far as I know, bots cannot interpret javascript - so I wanna make sure the URL remains obfuscated or even better, hidden, if they just scan the source code of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking too much into this to be honest.

If they want to avoid the confirmation screen and get the URL from the source, there's not really much you could do.

The best really is possibly performing an AJAX request on confirmation and getting a CSRF token based URL from the response and using that, but that could end up being overkill as well.

You could also make it into an actual `<form></form>` form with a few hidden fields (again, such as a CSRF token), and perform the post validation onclick. If it a success - redirect them.

UPDATE:

Use robots.txt to stop bots 
Build the QS with JS to stop most bots, something like:

```
var csrftoken='XJIWHEOU324uipHFOFUHR'; 
var url="http://url.com/page.php?token="; 
url=url+csrftoken;
```

What you could also do, is something like us actually, although for your use case it could be too much. 
Log every single page load into the DB, and check if if they're a first time visitor to the page after confirmation.

AJAX call (jQuery example):

```
$.post( "url_to_backend_page_to_get_url", {hasSubmittedForm:"true"}, function( data ) {
 window.location.href = data;
});
```

Comment: What I mostly wanna do, is make sure automated bots cannot get that URL directly by scanning the source code of the page. Legitimate human visitors are not my problem.

Comment: Use robots.txt to start. But yes, if you use a CSRF token they're pretty much stuck. In that sense, what you could actually do is add the URL together using JS like so `var csrftoken='XJIWHEOU324uipHFOFUHR'; var url="http://url.com/page.php?token="; url=url+csrftoken;'`. Straight away bots are stuck as barely any can parse JS. The ones that can, there's no point in trying.

Comment: I've updated my answer - that is a very weak example and I'd suggest adding bits to it, because I don't know anything about how your system is built

Comment: Thank you for the help - what I actually ended up doing was divide the URL of the page that I am redirecting to into 2 variables - the URL itself, and the security token I am issuing via PHP, and then concatenating them with JS concat.