# How to hide view source

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could some one please help me out to hide a view source option of a web page in dot net ?

Comment: If you hide the source the browser will no longer be able to see it and render your page and if the browser can see it, the user can also. I hope you are not storing passwords in HTML :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide html page source ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191566/hide-html-page-source)

Comment: would be helpful to know in what context/purpose

Comment: If you're talking about the view source option in the browser, then this is not really related to C#.

Answer (score 9):

You can't, it is an option of the browser. The best you can do is obfuscate it.

Comment: @Mark not if your goal is to check off a simple checkbox on a requirement worksheet like PCI for example. I've seen this a lot.

Comment: I agree. The best you can do is minify the HTML and maybe rename the name/id/class and similar attributes to some meaningless phrases so no one can deduct what they're for from the name. But be careful to make CSS and JS compatible with this. The end result will still have to be readable adn rendrable by the user's browser.

Answer (score 4):

Back in the Geocities era of the internet it wasn't uncommon for sites to use javascript to capture right clicks and popup a message box saying that you weren't allowed to view the source (or save an image or something).

This isn't quite so common nowadays for three main reasons:

1. It was futile. Preventing someone from using right click to view the source did nothing, as there are plenty of other ways to get at it. It was a minor inconvenience at best. If the browser can render the HTML, the user can get at it too.
2. It was annoying. Not just the modal message box whenever you accidentally right clicked. Arbitrarily removing functionality from the user's browser is a no-no.
3. It serves no purpose. If there is some reason that you *really* don't want the user to see the source of the website then there is something really wrong. If you are doing it to hide how bad the code is, fear not, terribly awful code makes it to production all the time. If you're doing it out of security then this is a *majorly* bad decision. Security through obscurity (on its own) is **never** the right choce.

That said, there are ways of obfuscating the code such that the browser can still parse it, but that it is at least annoying for a human to do so. You can use javascript to write certain parts of the page (a la AJAX) such that viewing the vanilla source code doesn't show what it actually rendered. Or you can compress it removing all formatting and naming elements (once it goes to production) such that it is at the very least annoying to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with Internet Explorer only, you can use [Group Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy) to disable the Internet Explorer **View Source** menu item.

See Group Policy entry: [View menu: Disable Source menu option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms814894.aspx).

Group Policy modifications are usually made through `gpedit.msc` or Active Directory.  However, in the most basic scenarios changes to Group Policy can be made via direct edits to the registry.