# how to encode html pages that could not decode it again

Tags: html, encode

i have a HTML page that want to encode it so could not decode it again but want to show it on all browsers correctly.
i know that exists a program called **Encrypt Web Pro** can do it but we know encoded html page with it can decode again easily.
do you know a safe way for this? please Help Me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some good ways to prevent people from copying my source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562775/what-are-some-good-ways-to-prevent-people-from-copying-my-source-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [free obfuscating HTML encoder](http://www.ioncube.com/html_encoder.php) you can encode your php output into an encrypted javascript. Viewing the source directly will result in one encoded line of javascript. This does not benefit the search engine optimization, and the source can still be viewed using a source debugger such as Firebug for firefox browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because to display the page, the browser would need to read the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

If a web browser needs to render your HTML (thats the whole point of HTML anyways), technically it can not be encrypted: by definition, the browser could not read the HTML, unless you also included the decryption key, which is pointless since it defeats the whole purpose of encryption.

I think what you are looking for instead is an HTML obfuscator: some way to mess up the HTML so that it is hard to understand for a human, but that browsers can decode without trouble.

edit: googling html obfuscator throws plenty of results

It would help if you provided any further information on what you are trying to achieve.