# How to secure Ionic web app source code in firebase hosting?

Tags: ionic3, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

Since I have to deploy my `/www` directory of my ionic app, I wonder how secured is my app in public directory. People can access `/www/build` folder therefore they can easily copy my whole project.

Is there any way to prevent them?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562775/what-are-some-good-ways-to-prevent-people-from-copying-my-source-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some good ways to prevent people from copying my source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562775/what-are-some-good-ways-to-prevent-people-from-copying-my-source-code)

Comment: That's not any solution. There should have some prevention system that PL offers like: php. But JS is client side code.
It would be better if firebase offered some protection system like google cloud functions. You cannot see JS code but output

Comment: Firebase provides an integration with Google Cloud Functions. See  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Answer (score 0):

**There is an option to prevent unauthorized access.**

1) Put your script in firebase storage

2) Add rules for the storage access

3) Serve them in hosting

But this is only for trusted users. 
You cannot open public registration against this method.